# Can you run Linux Mint in a virtual box on Linux Mint?

Tags: unity, gnome, virtualbox, mint

Ok, so to clarify, say I was running Mint 14, and I made a VBox, could I have the VBox run

Mint 14? The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to run different GUIs on Mint,

currently I'm using KDE. I am trying to run GNOME 3 and Unity, but when I switch GUIs they

are both extremely slow, and it seems like they are missing some things. For example,

there is about 4 different applications missing from the

launcher in Unity. So, I want to run them in the VBox to try and diagnose the problem,

and if they do freeze I can just close the VBox window.

I am not that skilled with computers and am still getting used to Linux (I have only

known about it for 6 months) so please break down your responses into basic thorough steps.

Also, if the answer to my question is yes, then would I have to re-download Mint and

save it as an ISO or is it stored somewhere on my pc? Because right now I am getting

the error message: "Fatal: No bootable medium found! System halted!" I dont know

exactly what this means or how to explain it, but I read that it basically means I need to give the VBox an ISO file to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Most questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives are classified as *off-topic*. This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run the same Linux Mint version (or any other OS for that matter) inside a VBox just fine.  The two are basically running independent of each other, just sharing the hardware at the direction of the hypervisor (which determines who gets the hardware at what point).

It sounds like you don't have the .iso file for Mint set as the bootable medium properly.  Try this:

1. With the VM *shut down completely*, Right-click on the VM in the list in VBox, and select "Settings..."
2. Click "Storage" in the left hand menu
3. Under "Controller: IDE" select the CD/DVD icon
4. On the very right there is another CD/DVD icon with a small down arrow.  Click that and select "Choose a virtual CD/DVD file"
5. Select the Mint .iso file (or whatever OS you're installing)
6. Check the box next to "Live CD/DVD"
7. Reboot the VM and it should launch into the install for Mint.  Run the installer.
8. After the install, shut down the VM
9. Go back to the drop down menu with the small down arrow next to the CD/DVD icon
10. Select "Remove disk from virtual drive"
11. You should now be able to boot into Mint (or whatever you installed)

Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: So, according to step 5, I would have to re-download Mint as an iso file, because I cannot find it when I go to select a vitual CD/DVD file. If it makes any difference; I installed Mint using a live CD. I dont understand why I would have to re-download Mint as an iso when I am running it right now!

Comment: Are you booted into the live CD or is mint installed?

Comment: Mint is installed

Comment: OK good. Then no you don't need the iso file again, you can set the CD instead of the iso and it should work fine

Comment: Wait a second, sorry, it was downloaded and installed from the website, I believe, without a live CD. So now what do I do?

Comment: I would download the .iso file and follow the instructions above.  That would be the easiest way IMO.